# I am developing an app in rails that requires retrieving the total number of votes per day

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am developing an app in rails that requires retrieving the total number of votes per day.

I  have the following migrations,

```
class CreateVotes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :votes, :primary_key => :vote_id do |t|
      t.string  :client_id
      t.integer :satlevel_id
      t.integer :service_id
      t.date  "date", :default => Date.today

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateSatlevels < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :satlevels, :primary_key => :satlevel_id do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

currently, i have the following in my controller.

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController
  def index
    render :layout => 'admin'
  end

  def forth
    @votes = Vote.all
    @satlevel = Satlevel.all 
    @result = Satlevel.joins(:votes)
    @result2 = @result.find_by_sql("select name, date, count(*) as 'total_votes' from satlevels left join votes on satlevels.satlevel_id = votes.satlevel_id group by satlevels.satlevel_id ")
  end
end
```

and this is what i have in my view,

```
<tr width = "100%"> 
  <th>DATE</th>     
  <% @result2.each do |result| %> 
    <th><%= result.name%></th>
  <% end%>
</tr>

<% @result2.each do |result| %> 
  <tr> 
    <td><%= result.date %></td>
    <% @result2.each do |result| %>
      <td><%= result.total_votes %></td>    
    <% end %>
<% end %>

</tr>
<tr>
```

This  outputs the total number of votes for each day but instead of having one row for each date, each  vote has its own row and date displayed together with the total votes.

I need help to output the count of all objects created in one day into a single row

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're asking here, but it looks like you're grouping by `satlevel_id` instead of on the date?  From your view code it looks like you're wanting to group by Date AND Name?  Are you trying to get the number of votes for each name on each day?

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure what you're asking here, but it looks like you're grouping by satlevel_id instead of on the date? From your view code it looks like you're wanting to group by date AND name?

Also, are you not following Rails conventions with your naming? Is your `satlevels` table's id actually `satlevel_id` or is it just `id`?

Making the assumptions that you're trying to count the number of occurrences for a name and a date AND you ARE actually using Rails conventions, here's how I would write the method:

```
def forth
  @result = Satlevel.select('satlevels.name, votes.date, count(votes.*) as total_votes')
                    .joins(:votes)
                    .group('satlevels.name, votes.date')
                    .order('satlevels.name, votes.date')
end
```